Why does a QPointer start with 2 weakref's, -1 strongref's?
I am trying to use QPointers, switching from raw pointers as I am trying to avoid memory problems.  I create an object using a QPointer like this:
QPointer<QFile> test = new QFile(...some file...);

I then insert a breakpoint right after, and at runtime I see that the test pointer has 2 weakref's right after creation, and -1 strong ref's.
Why does it have 2?  I just created it?
And what does -1 strong references mean?

These are implementation details and should really be of no concern to the end user.  If you really feel the need to know this then reading the source code should probably be your first step.

I'm trying to better understand how QPointer works, and this vars peeked my interested.  I don't want to start reverse engineering Qt source, but if someone has a ready explanation that's all I'm asking for.
